# Generate 2D grid with alternation probability

Tags: grid, 2d, probability-density

I want to generate a 2D grid environment with rewards distributed (1s are rewards, 0s are no rewards) based on an alternation probability as defined in [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.412.7679&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper by Falk and Konald.

The basic idea is that once a random square is seeded (top left, say) as 1 or 0, then the probability of the adjacent square staying the same as the previous, or switching - is given by the probability of alternation.

The paper describes the generation process as going from `left to right` and `top to bottom`. I am not clear on how the authors intended to implement it.

Algorithm:

- Seed top left square
- Left to Right: starting from 1,1 -- alternate with set probability
- Top to Bottom: starting from 1,1 -- alternate with set probability
- Obtain the reward matrix